# Trying to understand IIS permissions

Tags: iis, permissions, ntfs

I'm trying to understand how IIS permissions works because I had a weird scenario today..

So one of the developers installed IIS 10 on the server and created a site under C:\WebSites\Site1

Now, that particular site is also writing some txt log files to C:\Site1-Logs.

The Application Pool of Site1 is running as "ApplicationPoolIdentity".

Theoretically, The user running the site (IIS AppPool\Site1) should have the permission to write/create txt files under C:\Site1-Logs directory with out manually setting a permission for that?

Because I couldn't find any where under Security tab anything related to IIS_USRS group or "IIS AppPool\Site1" user.

When I tried to move the logs writing to another partition (E:) I had to give a writing permission to "IIS AppPool\Site1" and I can actually see the permission under Security tab.

So maybe I'm missing something? By default the IIS is installed as a system service and he already granted with permissions to write to C: ?

There is a best practice for that in terms of security? is it ok to run web applications under C: ?

Thanks and sorry for the bad explanation :P

```
icacls C:\Site1-Logs
C:\Site1-Logs        NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
                         BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
                         BUILTIN\Users:(I)(OI)(CI)(RX)
                         BUILTIN\Users:(I)(CI)(AD)
                         BUILTIN\Users:(I)(CI)(WD)
                         CREATOR OWNER:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
```

Comment: Can you add the NTFS permissions for C:\site1-logs like `icacls C:\site1-logs` to your question

Comment: Yes but what I don't understand is how my Application Pool have already access to write to folders under C:\ without giving specific permissions..

Comment: And I am trying to explain to you why that is the case, but for that you should list the permissions here.

Comment: lol sorry my bad :) Added the permissions to my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group `BUILTIN\Users` has Write Access to your `C:\Site1-Logs` directory.

The user `IIS AppPool\Site1` is automatically a member of the `Users` group because that is a special group under Windows.

This is why your web-site has write access.

You can't remove `IIS AppPool\Site1` from `users`, but you could remove the permissions of the `users` groups from the directory.

Comment: Thank you so much, It makes sense now how the user had write permission already. In terms of security, is it ok to keep BUILTIN\Users with write access to C: ? or should I remove that and give each individual user specific permissions ?

Comment: That depends on your environment. If you want to make sure one site can never read files belonging to another site, you should remove `users` permissions and use the individual site accounts for NTFS permissions.